# Commitizen: é possível sobrescrever o comando "git commit"?

Tags: git, commit

### Contexto

Gostaria de poder utilizar o comando `git commit` e ser executado o `cz`.

#### O que acontece

1. Instalo o Commitzen
2. Executo `git commit`
3. É aberta a interface comum do Git para criar a mensagem de commit

#### O que eu gostaria

1. Instalo o Commitzen
2. Executo `git commit`
3. É aberta a interface do Commitzen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei encontrando a documentação da ferramenta e descobri que existem duas formas, sendo elas:

### Alterando o hook do Git

Abra o arquivo `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg` e coloque o código abaixo:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec < /dev/tty && node_modules/.bin/cz --hook || true
```

### Alterando o hook do Git através do uso do Husky

Antes de começar, o [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) é uma ferramenta que auxilia na criação de hooks do Git em seu projeto Node.

Pra quem usa o Husky - assim como eu -, é só incluir no seu `package.json`:

```js
"husky": {
  "hooks": {
    "prepare-commit-msg": "exec < /dev/tty && git cz --hook || true",
  }
}
```